# Finding image present docx file using python

Tags: python

how i can find image images present in document file, is there any module for this in python. I searched but of no use. 
this is how we can read from word file . code below give no information about images present in file

```
 from  docx import Document

 documnet=Document('new-file-name.docx')
 para=documnet.paragraphs
     for par in para:
         print par.text
```

Comment: I would start with the [`InlineShapes`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/shape.html#inlineshapes-objects) property, but you're right - the documentation doesn't give any information on how to pull the image out of an `InlineShape` object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `.docx` files are zip files, you can use [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) module:

```
import zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile("1.docx")

#print list of valid attributes for ZipFile object
print dir(z)

#print all files in zip archive
all_files = z.namelist()
print all_files

#get all files in word/media/ directory
images = filter(lambda x: x.startswith('word/media/'), all_files)
print images

#open an image and save it
image1 = z.open('word/media/image1.jpeg').read()
f = open('image1.jpeg','wb')
f.write(image1)

#Extract file
z.extract('word/media/image1.jpeg', r'path_to_dir')
```

Comment: In python3, while printing images wrap the filter object with list().
>images = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('word/media/'), all_files))

or else filter object will be printed like "<filter object at 0x7fcd88d54eb8>"

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to first extract all image files as .zip, look for image elements in your XML code and relate each image to it's rId.

```
import os
import docx
import docx2txt

# Extract the images to img_folder/
docx2txt.process('document.docx', 'img_folder/')

# Open you .docx document
doc = docx.Document('document.docx')

# Save all 'rId:filenames' relationships in an dictionary named rels
rels = {}
for r in doc.part.rels.values():
    if isinstance(r._target, docx.parts.image.ImagePart):
        rels[r.rId] = os.path.basename(r._target.partname)

# Then process your text
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    # If you find an image
    if 'Graphic' in paragraph._p.xml:
        # Get the rId of the image
        for rId in rels:
            if rId in paragraph._p.xml:
                # Your image will be in os.path.join(img_path, rels[rId])
    else:
        # It's not an image
```

GitHub Repository Link: [django-docx-import](https://github.com/thalescr/django-docx-import)

Comment: This is the correct way to do it if you want to know exactly where the image was within the word doc