# Read images from docx file with python-docx

Tags: python, openxml, docx, python-docx

I have a docx file which contains images, shown as below in unzipped `document.xml` format.  Here, the particular images file is referred to by its id within the docx structure: `rId5`.

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:framePr w:h="13450" w:wrap="notBeside" w:vAnchor="text" w:hAnchor="text" w:xAlign="center" w:y="1"/>
    <w:widowControl w:val="0"/>
    <w:jc w:val="center"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:sz w:val="2"/>
      <w:szCs w:val="2"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:pict>
      <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
        <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
        <v:formulas>
          <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
        </v:formulas>
        <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
        <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
      </v:shapetype>
      <v:shape id="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:486pt;height:673pt;">
        <v:imagedata r:id="rId5" r:href="rId6"/>
      </v:shape>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

I tried to use the `document.inline_shapes` property to read the images, but the following prints 0:

```
PATH = "/home/amoe/test.docx"
doc = docx.Document(PATH)
print(len(doc.inline_shapes))
```

Is there any other way I can read this data?  I can see that the image is contained within a 'run', but I can't see any way to use the API of the `docx.text.Run` class to access the image.  The id of the `imagedata` element would be enough.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and from what I see you cannot read the image data with python-docx API, just change basic properties if the image (i.e. the shape that holds it).

Answer (score 2):

[Refer to](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html) python-docx 0.8.9 documentation

> Word documents have two layers, a text layer and a drawing layer.
>   When a picture appears in the text layer it is called an inline picture.
>   At the time of writing, python-docx only supports inline pictures.

I assume your pictures in the drawing layer, so you can't read the pictures by python-docx.

You can read this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27705408/8484506